# Rails 6: How to delete an element from a not-yet-persisted ActiveRecord Associations CollectionProxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-6

Suppose the following model situation:

```
class Library < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

How would I correct the below deletion command (which is wrong because `@library.books` is not a Ruby `Array` but a Rails `ActiveRecord Associations CollectionProxy`)?

```
@library.books.delete_if {|book| book.page_count < 100}
@library.save
```

Note:

`@library` and `@library.books` are not-yet persisted in the database (thus, they don't have IDs yet).

The deletion should not touch the database, but happen exclusively in the `ActiveRecord Associations CollectionProxy` *before it is persisted* in the database using `@library.save`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reassigning `books` collection:

```
@library.books = @library.books.select { |book| book.page_count >= 100 }
```